# DatastoreException: The given key doesn't have a String name value but a conversion to String was attempted

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Changed @Id type from Long to String in GCP datastore using spring java Repository.

```
DatastoreDataException
org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.mapping.DatastoreDataException: The given key doesn't have a String name value but a conversion to String was attempted
```

Comment: You are posting just an error but you are not providing us with any reproduction step or expected behaviour. Can you please expand your situation describing what are you trying to achieve and how are you doing it?

Answer (score 1):

So Keys in datastore can either have the property `id` which is a number or the property `name` which is a string.

I included 2 screenshots of an example of each

Numeric `id`:
[image]

String `name`:
[image]

So when you say this:

> Changed @Id type from Long to String in GCP datastore using spring java Repository.

What did you actually do?

It sounds like you just changed a model definition in your ORM. This doesn't actually change anything already stored in the datastore, it only impacts new entities going forward. So it sounds like, you're fetching entities with `id`s but your model definition is expecting them to have `name`s.

You would have to have some kind of data migration job convert them all over. Convert isnt even the right word since changing the key to use `name` instead would just create a new entity. You would have to delete the old entities that use `id` in this process.

You would also have to update all other entities that have key properties to this kind too.

Answer (score 0):

So we changed the Id from Long to String. And datastore table was already created with Long Id. so when we changed it we saw the above exception. By creating new table with String Id we resolved the issue.